# Test Account missing payment methods

Tags: opayo

I am in the process of testing my website integration with a SagePay test account. Everything was working as expected until the payment methods suddenly disappeared; has anyone else come across this issue?

I have three payment methods set up in my SagePay account.

[image]

Comment: Have you changed the AccountType= value at all?

Comment: No - nothing has changed since it last worked.

Comment: It sounds like there isn't any payment method associated with the merchant number that the account type and currency combination causes to be selected. You'll need to contact Sage Pay - sounds like something has gone wrong....

Comment: @Ash did you ever solve this issue as something similar occurred with a colleague recently?